# wxpython and multisplitter window

Tags: wxpython

I have a mutlisplitterwindow and in that window is a panel with a textctrl in it. Lets say there are 1000 lines in the text ctrl, but I want to specifically scroll to say line 450 and put that at the top of my window ... how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find anything specific on the topic, but you might try one of the following TextCtrl methods: SetInsertionPoint or ShowPosition.

See also http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TextCtrl-class.html

You might have better luck with one of StyledTextCtrls though. Then you can change other features too, like text color: http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl-class.html

Comment: I've never used the styledTextCtrl but it does have a function that I think would work ... ShowLines() ... still trying to get it to display text though haha

Comment: You should check out the wxPython demo. It has an example.

Comment: yeah I got the code working last night, the wxPython demo was fairly helpful but I felt it left out a few things, but I managed to work with it. The only thing I noticed is that the ShowLines() function does not adjust the scroll downwards. Meaning that if your text is below the visible area, it won't scroll to it, if its above the visible area, it works fine ...

Comment: So I've noticed that the call to GetLineCount() at the time I call ShowLines() is 1 ... however, there are 50 lines of text in the STCtrl ...

Comment: Ok ... so I've managed to get everything returning the correct values, but I simply cannot get it ShowLines() to do anything ... I can however, do ScrollToLine() and add some logic to make sure that a range is visible but I was under the impression that ShowLines() should do this ... or am I misunderstanding the functionality of ShowLines() ?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I seem to recall Robin mentioning that ScrollToLines was the right method to use. You can ask on the wxPython mailing list.